# Difficult Second Order Nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been attempting to create a model for a particular physical phenomena. I've reached the stage where I need to find the solution to a differential equation in order to continue. I've attempted to solve it on my own through a substitution but was unable to get anywhere with it. I am aware that the differential equation may not solvable so I will provide a few different forms. If any of these are solvable please let me know.

a) $y'' + (y')^2 = sin(y) $

b) $y'' + (y')^2 = y $

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Do you have initial or boundary conditions? Are you considering numerical solutions or only analytical solutions?

Comment: I had an analytical solution in mind. However, if this is not possible a numerical solution would suffice.

Comment: Note that $y''=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}(y'^2/2)$ to reduce to a first-order linear equation in $y'^2$...

Comment: If you just want the general behavior of the solution around a point $x_0$, one may try to do local analysis such as dominated balance to obtain an approximate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = (y')^2$. You can transform as follows:

$$ y'' = \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(y'^2)}{2y'} = \frac12\frac{\dfrac{du}{dx}}{\dfrac{dy}{dx}} = \frac12\frac{du}{dy} $$

Then

$$ \frac{du}{dy} + 2u = 2g(y) $$

where $g(y)$ is any function on your RHS. This is a standard first-order equation in $u(y)$.

Once you have $u(y)$, it remains to solve

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \pm\sqrt{u(y)} $$

which is a separable equation

Comment: It would appear that when $g(y) = sin(y) $ or $ g(y) = y$, it is not possible to integrate $u(y)$.

Comment: It usually isn't possible to represent the solution in closed form. If you have some initial conditions, you can use numerical integration.